# Displaying list items via SP.ClientContext

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, list-item

I am currently using SP.ClientContext via JavaScript to display items from a SharePoint list.  I am able to display the items via an alert or via input button  onClick to display the data.  However, I want it to display onLoad.

I am currently using an iframe tag to do so but it runs very slow.  When I run the Dev Tool in Chrome it states "Page cannot be found" (I suspect it's trying to locate the source and I'm not referencing the source correctly...currently using src="DispForm.aspx" but I'm sure that's incorrect).

Is there another way of displaying the items onLoad via JavaScript or finding the correct src reference for the iframe tag?  Below is the code I am using:

```
    <!--iframe is slow...maybe because it's looking for DispForm.aspx?-->
    <iframe style="display:none" onload="runCode()" src="/DispForm.aspx"></iframe>
    <span id="Sig"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var itemId = GetUrlKeyValue("ID");  
        var targetListItem;
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");               
       function runCode() {
         var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
         var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(myList');
         targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
         clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'ws_x002d_sig');
         clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
       }

       function onQuerySucceeded() {
            if (targetListItem.get_item("ws_x002d_sig")==="" || targetListItem.get_item("ws_x002d_sig")==null) {
                var prefVar= "<a href='#ws'>Sign</a>";
            }
            else {
                var prefVar=targetListItem.get_item('ws_x002d_sig');
            }

            var myObject = {
                prefObject: function() {
                    return prefVar;
                }
            }

            x = myObject.prefObject();
            document.getElementById("Sig").innerHTML = x;
            //"alert works great" alert('Request succeeded. \n\nRetrieved Item is: ' + targetListItem.get_item('ws_x002d_sig'));
        }

       function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
         alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
       }                

    </script>

    <!--input button works great -->
    <!--<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Run Code" onclick="runCodeWs()" />-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use jQuery **$(document).ready()** Method?
I've used in similar situation to retrieve context's user role to show/hide certain sections of the page.

Here is a jQuery Code Snippet; was added using SharePoint Designer.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   var LoggedOnUserRole="";   
   var dialogResult;

    $(document).ready(function () {

    //run the code only after sp.js has been loaded
      SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

      dialogResult= SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("", "Please wait..", 100, 200);       

      GetCurrentUserRoles();

      dialogResult.close(0);   

      });
  }); 
    </script>   
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is something I might use on another component of the SharePoint site. When a user clicks on "sign", if I'm reading your code correctly, a modal popup will show.  I'll just capture the users "ID",  add a date stamp, and add the   "signature" as a list item.

Comment: No, the pop-up here is for wait screen. You can get user info by getting currentWeb from the current context and then currentWeb.get_currentUser(); I can share "GetCurrentUserRoles()" function if you would like

Comment: thanks, I think I got the get current user.  I was looking for the SP.UI.ModalDialog as one of my solutions.  I think I can get your wait screen  and use it as a popup signature though that I was thinking of creating.  I'll probably have to create a separate post for that though (using Modal dialog box form to update items in a list).

Answer (score 0):

Sample test demo( not sure the requirement why you get item id from iframe url).

```
<iframe id="MyIFrame" style="display:none" src="/Lists/MyList/DispForm.aspx?ID=1"></iframe>
    <span id="Sig"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var itemId ;
        var targetListItem;
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
        function runCode() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
            targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
            clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Title');
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }

        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            if (targetListItem.get_item("Title") === "" || targetListItem.get_item("Title") == null) {
                var prefVar = "<a href='#ws'>Sign</a>";
            }
            else {
                var prefVar = targetListItem.get_item('Title');
            }

            var myObject = {
                prefObject: function () {
                    return prefVar;
                }
            }

            x = myObject.prefObject();
            document.getElementById("Sig").innerHTML = x;
            //"alert works great" alert('Request succeeded. \n\nRetrieved Item is: ' + targetListItem.get_item('ws_x002d_sig'));
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
        function Initialize() {
            var CurrentUrl = document.getElementById('MyIFrame').contentWindow.location.href;
            itemId = GetUrlKeyValue('ID', false, CurrentUrl)
            runCode();
        }
    </script>
```